# passing data from javascript to twig in Shopware 6

Tags: symfony, shopware

"I have the following problem: In Shopware 6, I created a plugin that includes its own table in the database. After that, I created a service to fetch data from this table, and I used this service through a controller to make the data available as JSON. Then, I fetched this data using a self-programmed JavaScript plugin, processed the data through this plugin, and now comes my question: How can I pass the result or the processed data from my JavaScript plugin to a Twig file? At some point, I read that I need to create a custom controller for this and send/transfer the data from this controller to my custom CMS element. However, I don't know how to do that. Could someone explain it to me?"